# Connect to Oracle with PHP using oci8 module and a dynamic connection string

Tags: php, oracle10g, oci8

I would like to connect to an Oracle DB from PHP using the oci8 module (oci_connect). I know how to do this, but the problem is I would like to do it dynamically based on a connection string of type

**"oci8://user_name:password@tns_name"**

The oci_connect method needs the user_name, password and the tns_name (called connection string) separately. I would prefer not to parse my connection string to make the code more robust.

Is there a way to do this ?

By the way, I'm using PHP 5.2.5 and Oracle 10g and I'm using the oci8 module to help me call a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code willbe more robust WHEN you parse your string, because you can detect invalid connection information

Comment: Not exactly what I expected... I think that a good php function can do some "magic" and adapt to different kind of connection string, my parsing won't. Still, thank you for your answer. Will mark it as resolved.